# Using Bulk Collect to populate specific columns

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Most of the examples online are about `select * bulk collect ...`

I have a script that grants synonyms and it takes too long to fetch data from the cursor, so I was planning to use bulk collect. The original cursor and the fetch:

Comment: The errors don't seem to match the code. The errors are mentioning `%TYPE`, but all I see in the code is `%ROWTYPE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with `vUser` and `vObjectName` should be collections of strings, not rowtypes on cursors. Or a single variable like `vRow` that is the rowtype of the cursor, and then access the members of the row `vRow(indx).grantee`.

If you are not going to use a `limit` clause on the `fetch bulk into` then you only need one loop, just on the collection, since everything will be grabbed at once.